# Converting sql query WITH clause query to mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am  converting my sql queries to mysql queries, but all the queries which have WITH clauses are failing.

Here is the query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT sto.NDate AS NDate,sto.NStockName AS StkName,sto.NClosingPrice AS StkClosingPrice, sto.NVolume AS StkVolume, 
    ind.NStockName AS IndName,ind.NClosingPrice AS IndClosingPrice, ind.NVolume AS IndVolume,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sto.NStockName ORDER BY sto.NDate)
    FROM equitystockoptions_nse AS sto
        JOIN equitystockoptions_indices AS ind ON sto.NDate = ind.NDate
    WHERE ind.NStockName='NIFTY' AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) >= DATE_FORMAT(v_fromdate,'%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) <= DATE_FORMAT(v_todate,'%m/%d/%Y')
)
SELECT curr.NDate,curr.StkName,curr.StkClosingPrice, curr.StkVolume, curr.IndName, curr.IndClosingPrice, curr.IndVolume,
 LOG(curr.StkClosingPrice / prev.StkClosingPrice) AS StkReturnOnLog, LOG(curr.IndClosingPrice / prev.IndClosingPrice) AS IndReturnOnLog
FROM CTE curr
INNER JOIN CTE PREV ON prev.rownum = curr.rownum - 1 AND curr.StkName = prev.StkName
ORDER BY StkName, NDate;
```

Any suggestion on this conversion is appreciated.

Comment: It's not only the common table expression, the query also uses window functions and a non-standard way of defining a column alias.

Answer (score 0):

WITH lets assign a name to an inline view (a subquery used in the FROM clause). As I know MySQL doesn't support WITH, so you can just replace all "CTE" references with the actual subquery:

```
SELECT  curr.NDate,curr.StkName,curr.StkClosingPrice, curr.StkVolume, 
        curr.IndName, curr.IndClosingPrice, curr.IndVolume,
        LOG(curr.StkClosingPrice / prev.StkClosingPrice) AS StkReturnOnLog, 
        LOG(curr.IndClosingPrice / prev.IndClosingPrice) AS IndReturnOnLog
FROM (
    SELECT sto.NDate AS NDate,sto.NStockName AS StkName,sto.NClosingPrice AS StkClosingPrice, sto.NVolume AS StkVolume, 
    ind.NStockName AS IndName,ind.NClosingPrice AS IndClosingPrice, ind.NVolume AS IndVolume,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sto.NStockName ORDER BY sto.NDate)
    FROM equitystockoptions_nse AS sto
        JOIN equitystockoptions_indices AS ind ON sto.NDate = ind.NDate
    WHERE ind.NStockName='NIFTY' AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) >= DATE_FORMAT(v_fromdate,'%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) <= DATE_FORMAT(v_todate,'%m/%d/%Y')
) curr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sto.NDate AS NDate,sto.NStockName AS StkName,sto.NClosingPrice AS StkClosingPrice, sto.NVolume AS StkVolume, 
    ind.NStockName AS IndName,ind.NClosingPrice AS IndClosingPrice, ind.NVolume AS IndVolume,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sto.NStockName ORDER BY sto.NDate)
    FROM equitystockoptions_nse AS sto
        JOIN equitystockoptions_indices AS ind ON sto.NDate = ind.NDate
    WHERE ind.NStockName='NIFTY' AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) >= DATE_FORMAT(v_fromdate,'%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sto.NDate,'%m/%d/%Y')) <= DATE_FORMAT(v_todate,'%m/%d/%Y')
) PREV ON prev.rownum = curr.rownum - 1 AND curr.StkName = prev.StkName
ORDER BY StkName, NDate;
```

Comment: MySQL also doesn't support window functions (`row_number()`)  and non-standard column alias using `rownum = ...` syntax

Comment: please explain how to find row_number() in this case